# Display two arrays in the same table

Tags: php, arrays

```
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$num_rows = count($row);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++)
{
    $title = htmlspecialchars($row[$i]['title']);
    $author =htmlspecialchars($row[$i]['author']);
    $school =htmlspecialchars($row[$i]['school']);
    $solution = $row[$i]['solution'];
    $notes = $row[$i]['notes'];

    $ad = array($title, $price, $author, $school, $contact, $content, $date);
    $inlcude = array($solutions, $notes);

    $field = 0;
    echo "<table border='1'>";    
    // foreach($inlcude as $in) This failled miserably 
    foreach ($ad as $post)
    {
        if ($field < 3) //The first three values are placed in the first row

        {
            echo "<td>$post</td>"; 
        }
        if ($field >= 3) 
        {         
            echo "<tr><td>$post</td><td>$in</td></tr>";   
        }
        $field++;
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

I have two arrays and I would like to display them in different columns in my table. $ad displays perfectly fine but I'm having trouble displaying the contents in $inlcude in the second column. I've tried putting another foreach loop to iterate through contents of the second array but that really screws up my table by placing random values in different places on the table. Besides the foreach loop, I don't know of any other way to iterate through the array. Any suggestions would be appreciated.Thanks!

I want the graph to look like this where $p=$post and $i=$in. Moreover, three columns in first row and two columns in every row after that

```
$p $p $p 

$p $i 

$p $i
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Do both arrays have the exact same number of key/value pairs?

Comment: Hey @Dan, thanks for the reply but the array's do not have the exact same number of key/value pairs.

Comment: @MarkOrmesher, I could not find a picture of how I wanted my graph to look online but I posted a layout which I hope helps. If not, I'll try to remake the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your arrays are formatted correctly, you probably want to use array_shift().  Try something like this:

```
// Start by copying the $include array, because array_shift() is a destructive
//   operation and you might want to use $includes again.
$includes_copy = $include;
// Start with your leading <tr> cell.
echo "<tr>";
// Now loop your ad array.
foreach ($ad as $post) {
  //The first three values are placed in the first row.
  if ($field < 3) {
    echo "<td>$post</td>"; 
    $field++;
  }
  if ($field == 3) {
    echo "</tr>";  // Closing tags are good form.
  }
  if ($field >= 3) {
    // Using array_shift() will return the first element from the array.
    // The returned element will be removed from the array.
    $in = array_shift($includes_copy);
    // $post is populated from foreach(), $in is populated by array_shift(). 
    echo "<tr><td>$post</td><td>$in</td><td></td></tr>";
    $field += 3;   
  }
}
```

Basically, the concept is that foreach($array as $val) is logically equivalent to while($val = array_shift($array)), meaning that you can run two foreach() at the same time.  The only difference is that array_shift() is destructive.

Comment: This works perfectly except for one thing. The third element in the $ad array is displayed in the last column of the first row and in the first column in the second row. I do not need the latter one there. Any suggestions on how to go about this?